# Post URL duplication adds numerical value

Tags: posts, urls, seo

I thought that belonging to these different categories url naming posts the same would be treated as distinct.

Categories:

- Home
- Hotel

Posts:

- street
- street

URL generated:

1. www.my.com.br/casa/street-a
2. www.my.com.br/hotel/street-a-2

> I wonder how to solve this, I imagine that it affects> SEO <.

What is the solution to set that House and Hotel BELONG the same street to avoid being added this numerical value 2?

Comment: Helper???
??????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posts have a slug (that's the last part of the URL), and it must be distinct, even if posts are in different categories.

If your only worry is SEO, don't worry.  Google sees the URLs as distinct, and Google is used to dealing with URLs that have a suffix on them, and has no problems with it. The keywords in the URL are still the same and have the same value.

If you still want to change this, you could manually change the slug when you create the post, or you could hook into save_post and change the slug to be street-casa.  But there is no need.